# How do you complete this question? “This is easily the most difficult question in the game (LOL, just kidding).”

Tags: impossible-test-3

I'm pretty sure this question gets you the badge “Answer the most difficult question”. You get 1 second to answer it and if you don't answer it you just move on to the next question. How do you solve this?

[image: Question]

Comment: The letter "K"?

Comment: @Steve-O Thanks, that worked. I don't know why I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the letter “K”. You tap on the letter “K” in the word “BLACK” in the last line.